# jQuery how to remove href in content data

Tags: jquery, html, excel

I do export excel when user click on button export i get content html like this

```
<div id="tabledata">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><a href="www.abc.com">abc</a></td>
    <td>abc<hr/>012</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

I want remove `href` from this content and want replace tag `hr` to break line in excele. please help me.

this is my script

```
var tabdata = $("#tabledata").html();//above html is "tabdata"
var news = tabdata.find("a").removeAttr("href");
$("#tableval").val(news);
$("#sendtable").submit();
```

Comment: on whcih event you want to remove href tag ? and u want to just remove href or anchor tag completely to replace with hr tag ?

Comment: try giving your <td> or <a> an ID?

Comment: @swfong it's my example only, real data it's many place and multi row

Comment: @NalinAggarwal yes i want remove `href` and replace hr as my question from  content `tabdata`

Comment: I posted a snippet for removing all the href of your table. But cannot understand what you want about the `<hr/>`

Comment: @GilleQ. in content `tabdata` i want replace `hr` tag to break line in excel; example only for web break link we used `<br/>`

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `href` of all your `<a>` in the table doing this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#tabledata table td").each(function() {
        $(this).find("a").removeAttr("href");
        $(this).find("hr").replaceWith('<br class="exchange" style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"/>');
    });
});
```

There is a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/e4n7qpy5/)

Comment: your code work! I update your code to `$("#tabledata table").each(function() { $("a").removeAttr("href");$('hr').replaceWith('<br class="exchange" style="mso-data-placement:same-cell;"/>'); });`, it's work respond to my question but i am not sure it's right ways or not.